# Hard-Disk Partitioning: Please Help Me! :(

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

Guys i am new to linux and all that stuff. I installed ubuntu alongside windows 8.1 a few days ago and i am not happy with the hard disk partition so i installed gparted, i want to add the unallocated part to sda5. Is there anyway i can do it without shutting down my computer?
I was going to add a picture for more info but apparently my rep isn't high enough :) But here some info from gparted:

---

- **Partition** ......... **File System** ....... **Mount Point** ........... **Label** ................... **Size** ............ **Flags**
- /dev/sda1 ........ ntfs .............................. * ............. System Reserved ..... 350.00 MiB ...... boot
- /dev/sda2 ........ ntfs ...............................* .......................... * ................... 81.93 GiB ............ *
- unallocated ..... unallocated ..................* .......................... * ................... 18.54 GiB ............ *
- /dev/sda3 ........ extended ......................* .......................... * ................... 18.42 GiB ............ *

  - /dev/sda5 ........ ext4 ....................... / .......................... * ................... 14.51 GiB ............ *
  - /dev/sda6 ........ linux-swap ............* .......................... * ..................... 3.91 GiB ............. *

---

i used **(*)** for empty

---

And if it's important there was a key symbol next to sda 3-5-6

Comment: There is no way to do it without shutting down. You need to boot from Ubuntu LiveCD.

Comment: How can i get one?

Comment: This is the media you installed Ubuntu from.

Comment: So should i reinstall ubuntu from my usb?

Comment: You should boot from that usb, choose "Try Ubuntu", start gparted from there.

Comment: i forgot to ask what to do next :P

Comment: It depends on what you want to achieve ;-) Resize your partitions.

Comment: like i said i want to add unallocated to sda5 :D  because there is not much space in linux part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Boot from Ubuntu LiveUSB. Choose "Try Ubuntu" and start gparted.
2. Run in terminal `sudo swapoff -a`
3. Resize `sda3` partition left.
4. Resize `sda5` partition left.
5. Run in terminal

   ```
   sudo mount /dev/sda5 /mnt
   sudo chroot /mnt
   sudo grub-install /dev/sda
   ```
6. Reboot.